# Nifi Merge RecordProcessor Does Not Merge JSON received from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I use ConsumeKafka processor followed by Merge Records and PutHDFS processors.

What I observe is that regardless of Merge Record processor config - a lot of single record flow files are added to HDFS - i.e. merge doesn't not work at all.

However, if I put GenerateFlowFile processor and **produce exactly the same JSON and exactly with the same schedule (i.e. 0 sec)** - merge does work.

I see the "**Records Merged due to: Maximum number of bins has been exceeded**" for single file merges when Kafka is used. Still not clear why is it exceeded?

NiFi is not really great in logging. I'm really confused. Is it Kafka Consumer who makes the difference? Why does it work for GenerateFlowFile but not for Kafka?

Could please anyone suggest.

Thank you.